# What does this construction "<%= someName %>" mean in SCSS?

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend

I have a code in SCSS that looks like:

```
$bp-small: <%= breakpointSmall %>;
```

What does it mean and what is this called?

Comment: What's the file extension?

Comment: Appears to be _ASP.NET_ syntax but I'm not quite sure...

Comment: @War10ck could also be jsp, for that matter

Comment: it's .scss file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has no meaning in SCSS. The compiler reports this error:

> Error: Invalid CSS after "$bp-small: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "<%= breakpointS..."
>           on line 1 of test.scss

Probably: It is syntax from a template language used to preprocess the SCSS before it is passed to the SASS compiler.

Comment: hmm, what template language could it be?

Comment: Could be template toolkit. Could be EJS. Could be ASP.NET. It's a very very long list.